# El objeto json no se visuliza de manera correcta en swagger

Tags: c#, json, api, .net, asp.net-core

Estoy intentando devolver un objeto json por medio de una clase

```
public class ObjRes
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public JObject messages { get; set; }
}
```

y he intentado con JObject y JaveScriptSerializer

```
var response = client.PostAsync(e1, null).Result;
var value = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string resultat_Json = jss.Serialize(value);
JObject obj =  JObject.Parse(value);
return resultat_Json;
```

Y el objeto desde visual studio se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en el swagger se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De qué manera debo usar la conversión para visualizar los dato correctamente y no solo los corchetes cuadrados

Answer (score 0):

Podrías convertirlo a un diccionario cada propiedad de tu json añadirlo a una lista y retornar la lista

```
string JSONResult;
JSONResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TU JSON);
JArray JSONObject = JArray.Parse(JSONResult);
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (dynamic d in JSONObject)
{
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> obj = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    foreach (JProperty property in d.Properties())
    {
        string propertyName = property.Name;
        JToken propertyValue = property.Value;
        obj[propertyName] = propertyValue.ToObject<object>();
    }
    list.Add(obj);
}
```